# Proper way to use botframework-webchat in React component (using create-react-app)?

Tags: reactjs, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I've created an app using create-react-app, then used the official [github instructions](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) for integrating with React (v16.6.3):

```
import DirectLine from 'botframework-directlinejs';
import React from 'react';
import ReactWebChat from 'botframework-webchat';

export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.directLine = new DirectLine({ token: 'YOUR_BOT_SECRET' });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactWebChat directLine={ this.directLine } />
      element
    );
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: botframework_directlinejs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default.a is not a constructor
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, there is (at time of writing this) an error in the instructions in the official repo:

```
import DirectLine from 'botframework-directlinejs';
```

should be:

```
import { DirectLine } from 'botframework-directlinejs';
```

Change this, and botframework-webchat v4 works with React 16, with the instructions on the github page.

If you want to use v3 of botframework-webchat, the following code worked for me:

After some experimenting and [digging](https://github.com/compulim/BotFramework-WebChat-Repro-1198) in other repos, here's how I was able to do this using a clean create-react-app instance:

in /src/App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import * as WebChat from 'botframework-webchat';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { token: null };
  }

    async componentDidMount() {
    const myHeaders = new Headers()
    var myToken = process.env.REACT_APP_DIRECTLINE_SECRET
    myHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + myToken)
    const res = await fetch(
        'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders
        }
    )

    const { token } = await res.json()
    this.setState(() => ({ token }))
}

  render() {
    const {
      state: { token }
    } = this;

    return (
      !!token &&
        <WebChat.Chat
          directLine={{
            token,
            webSocket: false
          }}
          style={{
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%'
          }}
          user={{
            id: 'default-user',
            name: 'Some User'
          }}
        />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Add this line before the title tag in /public/index.html:

```
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/0.14.2/botchat.css"
    />
```

package.json -- note I'm using the 0.14.2 version of botframework-webchat, I can't get it to work on the master release (4.1.1 as of right now):

```
{
  "name": "react-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "botframework-webchat": "^0.14.2",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

And don't forget to set your secret in .env!